# Unable to redirect page on logging out in php

Tags: php, sql, session, logout

My links are of the sort : `http://example.com/events.php?slug=xyz`

where the [slug] fields are imported from the database.
The starting lines in my `events.php` page is:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$url="events.php?slug=".$slug."/";
....
....
```

My logout function:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}


<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){?>
    <a href="?logout" ><button>Log Out</button></a>
<?php }?>
```

But on clicking the `logout` `"http://example.com/events.php?slug=/"` is displayed.

My whole `php` script at the starting of the page is:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require_once('13/functions/db.php');
    $slug = $_GET['slug'];
    $url="events.php?slug=".$slug."/";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE slug='".$slug."'");
    if ($result == true){
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id=$row['id'];
        if($id>=13 && $id<=40 && $id!=17){//some checks.
            $var=1;
            $name=$row['name'];
        }
        else {
            $var=0;
            $name="404";
        }
    }

session_name('fewiui');
session_set_cookie_params(3*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}


$sess_uid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sess_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$sess_name = $_SESSION['name'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='Register')
    require_once('13/functions/eventlogin.php');    
?>
```

Everything else (like login, etc.) works. Where am I doing the mistake? I'm a newbie in php.

Comment: this behavior is intended as you set the variable $url="events.php?slug=".$slug."/"; and when you logout you redirect header('Location: ' . $url); where should it redirect then ?

Comment: @superbly: It should redirect to the same page. That may be of the form `events.php?slug=eventxyz`

Comment: then you have to forward the slug value in the logout link. $slug = $_GET['slug'];  <a href="?slug=$slug&logout" ><button>Log Out</button></a>

Comment: @superbly: It's still not working. Can you please write it again and post it as an answer. With that, I can mark it correct as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="?slug=<?php echo $slug; ?>&logout" ><button>Log Out</button></a>
```